# SQL Oracle join on CY and PY date ranges to identify price changes

Tags: sql, oracle

I have below two tables

[image]

[image]

~ What I am looking to do in Oracle SQL:

1. Append Price from Table 2 (t2) to Table 1 (t1), by joining on Product_NR, Quantity and YYYY_MM:

- t1.Product_NR = t2.Product_NR
- if t1.Quantity has no exact match with t2.Quantity, take the closest max Quantity value in t2 (i.e. if t1.Quantity  = 18, the closest max in t2.Quantity is 20)
- t1.Order_YYYMM should fall between t2.Price_Active_Date_From and  '999912' means the price is still active.

2. Also append t2.price that was active 1 year prior to the order date

So the result should look like:

[image]

I have tried below query which works for everything but the 'Price_Active_1Y_PriorOrder'. The output shows  more than 1 distinct price for 'Price_Active_1Y_PriorOrder', where t1.Quantity <= t3.Quantity. How to pull only the ONE value for Price_Active_At_Order and Price_Active_1Y_PriorOrder?

```
with Price_Table as (

select distinct
        t1.Product_NR,
        t1.Customer,
        t1.Quantity,
        t2.Price as Price_Active_at_Order,
        t3.Price as Price_Active_1Y_PriorOrder,
        t1.Oder_YYYMM as Order_Date,
        min(t2.Quantity) over (partition by t1.Product_NR) as Quantity_Order2, 
        min(t3.Quantity) over (partition by t1.Product_NR) as Quantity_Order3

from 
        Table_1 t1
        join Table_2 t2   on t1.Product_NR = t2.Product_NR
                                and t1.Quantity <= t2.Quantity
                                and t1.Order_YYYYMM     between t2.Price_Active_Date_From  and t2.Price_Active_Date_To
        
        join Table_2 t3   on t1.Product_NR = t3.Product_NR
                                and t1.Quantity <= t3.Quantity
                                and TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(t1.Order_YYYYMM , 'YYYYMM'), -12), 'YYYYMM')  between  t3.Price_Active_Date_From  and t3.Price_Active_Date_To     
        
)

select *
from Price_table

where Quantity = Quantity_Order2
        and Quantity = Quantity_Order3
```

Comment: There is 1 row in Table1 matching with 2 rows in Table2 i.e. for product_nr 10023, quantity 18 and Order_yyyymm 202104. How can 2 prices are active at the same time for a single product?

Comment: Hi what is the rule if, for example, t1.Quantity = 15 (exactly half way between 10 and 20)? Are you going for the nearest value or the first value that is greater than the input value?

Comment: @NickW, if t1.Quantity = 15, we want the closest value that is greater than or equal to 15. As there is no Quantity of 15 in t2, we want t2.Quantity = 20 (10 would be less than 15)

Comment: @NishantGupta, in my data, the price per product is based on quantity bands. Meaning, for the same Product_NR the price will change depending on the quantity purchased. If a customer buys the same product for t1.quantity = 18, the price will be different than if they bought t1.quantity = 6. That's why there are multiple prices active for the same product_NR. Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi - is it also the nearest (but greater) value that is active at the date of the Order? i.e. if the quantity=15 but there are no quantity=20 records active at the time of the order then it would pick the quantity=100 record (assuming that was active at the time of the order)?

Comment: @NickW yes that is correct!

Answer (score 0):

Solution for your problem:

```
SELECT 
t1.product_nr, t1.customer, t1.quantity, 
MIN(CASE WHEN t1.order_yyyymm >= t2.price_active_date_from AND t1.order_yyyymm <= t2.price_active_date_to THEN t2.price ELSE 99999 END) AS price_active_at_order,
MIN(CASE WHEN TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(t1.order_yyyymm,'YYYYMM'), -12), 'YYYYMM') >= t2.price_active_date_from AND TO_CHAR(ADD_MONTHS(TO_DATE(t1.order_yyyymm,'YYYYMM'), -12), 'YYYYMM') <= t2.price_active_date_to THEN t2.price ELSE 99999 END) AS price_active_1y_priororder,
t1.order_yyyymm AS order_date
FROM table_1 t1
JOIN table_2 t2 ON t1.product_nr = t2.product_nr AND t1.quantity <= t2.quantity
GROUP BY t1.product_nr, t1.customer, t1.quantity, t1.order_yyyymm
ORDER BY t1.product_nr, t1.customer;
```

For demo check out the below link:

[db-fiddle Link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=8fb996d6c5d94298212ed93df04f188e)